# Pakistan CNIC (expired) to NICOP

Tags: pakistani-citizens

I am looking for some clarity please. I have an expired CNIC and want to convert it to NICOP. I know it is possible but the PAK ID web site is a bit confusing with too many products and requirements. Can some one please give me easy to follow steps?

Also, can my existing fingerprints that are already in thesystem (verified that NADRA does have it), can the same fingerprints be used, or do I have to send them again?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had confirm with one of my known person he has gone through the same situation. He said that for the change of the nature of card you need to submit new thumb print. You can go with NADRA site or visit to NADRA mega center. In my opinion you should go for NADRA MEGA CENTER. They will guide you properly.

Comment: yeah but he gone through the same situation , so he knows

Comment: That your friend went through the same situation is very relevant, as it does support his statement that a new thumb print is necessary. Because comments can disappear while answers don't, it would be good to edit your answer (using the "edit" button below the answer text) to include this additional information in the answer text.

Comment: yeah thank you , let me update the above comment

Comment: Well done. I have deleted my original comment, and upvoted the answer.